# PHP duplicate output

Tags: php, html

I have a while loop fetching a row and I'm trying to create a structure so that each row will create 2 links. The first is a German word and the second being an English one. The output I'm getting is repeated as if the row isn't being incremented. I've narrowed it down to this:

PHP:

```
while ($row = $database->row()->fetch()) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $this->data .= $value . "!";
    }
    list($this->pid, $this->german, $this->english) = explode("!", $this->data);
    $this->links .= "<a href=\"#\" class=\"german $this->pid\">$this->german</a><br/><a href=\"#\" class=\"english $this->pid\">$this->english</a><br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
die Männer
men
die Männer
men
```

Comment: What database abstraction are you using?

Comment: @Orangepill I'm using PDO

Comment: Try getting the number of rows, and then setting `$n`, and after that, do a `while()` loop such as `while($n < $rows; $n++)`. If there is one row, just echo an output of the only one row. I am a mysqli person, and I don't like `foreach()`.

Comment: PDO doesn't have a `row` method last time I checked.

Comment: @PeeHaa It doesn't. I created a database object with a row method returning the query property.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $row = array();
    while ($row = $database->row()->fetch()) {
        $row[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($row as $value)
    {
        $this->data .= $value . "!";
        list($this->pid, $this->german, $this->english) = explode("!", $this->data);
        $this->links .= "<a href=\"#\" class=\"german $this->pid\">$this->german</a><br/><a href=\"#\" class=\"english $this->pid\">$this->english</a><br/>";
    }
```

Comment: I have a warning "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by looking at the keys and creating variables based on a simple matched string test. If anyone can improve my answer I would like to hear it. Thanks.

PHP:

```
while ($row = $database->row()->fetch()) {
    while(list($key, $value) = each($row)) {
        if ($key == "PID") {
            $this->pid = $value;
        }
        if ($key == "german") {
            $this->german = $value;
        }
        if ($key == "english") {
            $this->english = $value;
        }
    }
    $this->links .= "<a href=\"#\" class=\"german $this->pid\">$this->german</a><br/><a href=\"#\" class=\"english $this->pid\">$this->english</a><br/>";
}
```